# Will I fail probation?

Tags: probation

In a new role (Scrum Master), competent at it but not getting along with two individuals who have been there a long time.

Both individuals have not criticised my skillset, but have criticised character traits - not being engaging enough, lack of empathy. Nobody else has complained about this.

The issue I have is where I am trying to engage with them, but it seems as though for whatever reason they have, they do not want to engage and when they do are rude.

My manager has acknowledged my good work, but has sided with them.

I am paranoid that they are plotting to get rid of me, should I be concerned.

Comment: This is something we can't really answer... as we would be guessing...

Comment: You forgot to mention what type of job you do. As like a lack of empathy in something like a helpdesk job, yes I would be concerned, as it's a strong argument against your way to treat your customers.

Comment: Im a scrum master

Comment: Basically telling me that despite the good work I have done, I am at fault and need to find a way to work with them, ignoring their part in creating this situation and my efforts to build a bridge.

Comment: @bobo2000 Sorry to be brutal, but best efforts mean very little - results do. And so far you didn't deliver on the scrum bit, have you? Yes, you are facing opposition, but that's part of the job that you have to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, but we can only guess at whether you'll pass or fail your probation. Perhaps a question about how to better interact with the difficult individuals would be of more use?

Answer (score 4):

> Will I fail probation?

Based on comments here and your previous question, the crux of the issue appears to be that you believe you cannot accommodate these two long-time workers while still bringing Agile practices to your company.

Your manager has acknowledged your good work, but has made it clear that you need to find a way to work with them, or your manager will be unhappy. Unhappy managers are more likely to fail your probation.

**So nobody other than your manager can say that you *will* fail probation, but the signs are there if you cannot find a way forward.**

Success seems to involve both an effective Agile transition, and finding a way to work with the two individuals who are unhappy. The Agile Manifesto specifically states "Individuals and interactions over processes and tools". Failure for you seems to involve not accomplishing both.

Comment: That sums it up basically. Trying to actively build a bridge but PO and his peer are unhappy that I am there to guide the team to do agile properly. He seems to have the command and control mindset.

Comment: @bobo2000 I dont see it that way you state it, but I would state that if the manager told you that, he indirectly offer you a chance to get better. Maybe because you got the skill, but soft skill to manage a team is something else

Comment: There has definitely been a disagreement over the best approach to doing agile, mine is based on best practice and experience, theirs isn’t.

Comment: That’s true to a point. A scrum master is hired to coach the team to build a process which is based on the scrum framework and guard it. The problem is where these two individuals have no intention to follow the scrum framework, hence the conflict. When I remind them of best practice they get offended.

Comment: Its not being dogmatic for the sake of it , scrum is a framework based on the scrum guide - clearly says in the scrum guide that scrum masters are there to protect the agile process. If they don’t want to do scrum then they shouldn’t pretend to be agile - I have no problem doing other forms of project management, but people need to be clear what exactly they want my role to be.

Comment: @bobo2000 and that doesn't matter a bit. Welcome to the world where books end and people begin, and you are not the first person in history of the world to encounter resistance when implementing any sort of practice. And unless you are willing to find a working middle ground, instead just digging your heels shouting "THIS IS SCRUM THIS IS HOW IT WORKS", it's not going to work.

Comment: You are right Tymotuez, can’t but help but feel disappointed though . I was lead to believe at the interview process that they wanted to do things properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I am paranoid that they are plotting to get rid of me, should I be concerned.

Being paranoid never helps. Nor can't we guess if they are plotting "against" you.

Two things I can suggest:

1. Approach your manager and ask what they think of your soft skills and character traits, and if there is anything you can work or improve on.
2. If you *really* feel they want to get rid of you, I suggest you update your resume and start job-hunting just in case things happen as you thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you are nervous about them wanting to not renew your probation period because of feedback you have received, then you should ask the manager for direct feedback on the matter. This should clear up gray areas and help you know if these two guys are just inherently excused for being rude, or if this threatens your job prospects. Of course, whether or not you want to work somewhere that just gives these guys a pass is another question. I would talk to the boss and ask for his assessment of the probation period to this point in time.

Generally speaking, if I were looking for a job and started a probationary period at a new job, I would not stop looking for a job as a result since it isn't a guaranteed thing. I would especially continue to look if I thought there were red flags about the new workplace or things that made me wonder if the new place liked me or not.